# Sending reserved character as URL parameter value

Tags: angularjs, http, url, get, escaping

I have to send the parameter value `'AbCd/EfgH'` as is. But angular escaping the `'/'` to `%2F`. I don't have control over the `URL`.

What's the best approach to this problem?

I don't want to force angular to stop encoding all other URLs.

```
$http.get(URL, {
      params: {
        emv_ref: 'AbCd/EfgH',
        email: email
      }
});
```

Comment: did you try encodeURIComponent('AbCd/EfgH') ?

Comment: @alexandre encodeURIComponent will encode it right? ('/' to %2F). And angular will encode it again. I dont want to encode it. The value have to append it in URL as it is.

Comment: what url is send when you use urlencode ? or maybe you can use 'AbCd\/EfgH'

Comment: url is like http://<url>?email=<email>&ref=AbCd%2FEfgH normally, and when I used encodeURIComponent it's like http://<url>?email=<email>&ref=AbCd%252EfgH. I want it like http://<url>?email=<email>&ref=AbCd/FEfgH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular URL encodes all parameters, you can't just exclude one from this process. you just need to manually compose URL with necessary parameters. Use convenient [$httpParamSerializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer) service to serialize part of your parameters and append non-encoded to the string of params:

```
var params = $httpParamSerializer({email: email}) + '&emv_ref=AbCd/EfgH';
$http.get(URL + '?' + params);
```

Or much cleaner approach would be to use custom [paramSerializer](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) function:

```
$http.get(URL, {
    paramSerializer: function(params) {
        return $httpParamSerializer({email: email}) + '&emv_ref=AbCd/EfgH';
    }
});
```

.. or like this:

```
$http.get(URL, {
    params: {
        email: email,
        emv_ref: 'AbCd/EfgH'
    },
    paramSerializer: function(params) {
        var ref = '&emv_ref=' + params.emv_ref;
        delete params.emv_ref;
        return $httpParamSerializer(params) + ref;
    }
});
```

Comment: I have defined URL in my config and these emv_ref are very long. So you think this is the only way?

Comment: Custom paramSerializer looks good. Will give it a try. Thanks